# function declaration not being recognized

Tags: javascript

My code has a function declaration

```
var string = function(){..}
```

later in the code I use this as

```
var value = function(){

  ...
  string();
}
```

variable value is defined after string. There should be no reason why it should not recognize string as a function.

Plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/9tRZnIVlRkNadPXCKsla?p=preview

if you simply run the plnkr, the error will show up on ‍‍‍`line 98`

Comment: Calling a function `string` is probably asking for trouble anyway. (same for `value` actually). Use more meaningful function names!

Comment: As a side note, don't write your own JSON parser. It is a solved problem. /opinion

Comment: @Mathletics.. it's coding practice .. learning how problems were solved

Comment: @Moderator.. not sure what the reason behind giving me negative points ?? so many people got the answer wrong.. doesn't look like it was an obvious question.

Comment: @SMV: You question is a simple typo. Therefore it's not a useful question for anybody else. Doubly so since the question doesn't actually include the code *with the typo*.

Comment: Fair enough.. lets not waste bits.. will delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at line 42: you wrote `var hex, i, stirng = '';` and not `string`. Fix the variable name and it will work!

The fact that you have a variable named `string` inside a function called `string` is not a problem as some people are stating because of scope.
Inside you `string` function, any reference to `string` will be resolved to the inner variable `string`, and not the function.

Comment: The issue with naming anything `string` is not an issue of scope, it's an issue of being too-close-for-comfort to `String`, the JavaScript native object.

Comment: what perplexes me is the fact that the error was reported on line 98, instead of line 51.

Comment: @Mathletics I didn't said it was good practice or supported his naming convention. I added that part to the answer because people were posting wrong answers. I never said that it was good programming. The fact that my perfectly correct answer was voted down twice in a community like SO makes me cringe, tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line **42** of in your `string` function:

```
41 var string = function() {
42  var hex, i, stirng = ''; // typo 'stirng' for 'string'
43
```

so on line **53**, `string` refers to the function `string`. When you try to add a string `ch` to it, it is coerced into a string.

```
52      } else {
53        string += ch; // the function string is coerced to string
54      }
```

Then when it called on line **91**, `string` the function has been replaced by a string (the result of `string.toString() + ch`), resulting in the error `Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function`.

Comment: That isn't an issue. The scope is different. `function x() { var x = 1; console.log(x); }; x()`

Comment: In any case, its a bad practice to use such similar variable names, which is part of why this happened. If he used different variables, he would have gotten an `undefined` error which would be more easily traceable.

Comment: @Mathletics use the debugger and look at the output of `string` at the point that it breaks. I'm correct.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. I'm going to edit your answer to make it clearer.